# Web development - Asynchronous vs Synchronous

Tags: java, web-applications, asynchronous

I am currently reading about async programming and it seems to have a lot of advantages.

- But for web development should I make every request asnyc?
- Does async have disadvantages?

I am using Java with Play2 and async isn't really to best looking thing.
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaAsync

Comment: IMHO Asynchronous is often more complicated to use/implement. Asynchronous communication does have advantages, but keeping things simple as possible is often more important.

Comment: So if I don't really need something like real time updates, I should stick to sync?

Comment: That is what I would do.  You can implement real-time updates with synchronous calls, but its simpler in this case to use asynchronous calls.  Just go with what appears to be simplest to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the basis for your conclusion that async is the best? **It all depends upon the usecase**. You need to think about error handling, communicating the results back to the user if you choose async processing.